# Use struct without structure name as extern in another file

Tags: c, struct, extern

I am working with xv6 and there is a c file that contains this:

```
struct {
    struct spinlock lock;
    char buf[INPUT_BUF];
    uint r;  // Read index
    uint w;  // Write index
    uint e;  // Edit index
} input;
```

I don't want to edit this file, but I do want to use `input` in another file I made. I am not sure how to do this, external declarations like `extern input` and `extern struct input` do not work

Comment: An `extern` declaration requires type, which you cannot provide (assuming you meant it when you said you didn't want to modify this file) without replicating this structure declaration (and that may not be as straight-forward as it seems; alignment modifiers, packing, etc). There is no way you can simply `extern` the var `input` without type info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this correctly without editing the file;  two different untagged structs are considered to be different types.

It might "work" to repeat the struct definition in the other file, but that doesn't comply with the C standard.

Change this file to `struct input_t {` etc. and make the other file do `extern struct input_t {` ... `} input;`.

Of course it is preferable to put the struct definition (and any definitions it relies on such as `spinlock` or `INPUT_BUF`) in a common header file, this is to prevent ODR violations. If you don't do this then be very careful that both files are using the exact same struct definition. For example if `INPUT_BUF` were different in one to the other, then it will cause undefined behaviour .